# How to select current date from calendar using puppeteer?

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I want to select the current date from the calendar using puppeteer.After selecting the date, it should get display in the date field.Is there simple way i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard because Puppeteer depends on physical location (x,y) to click it, so you'd have to tell it where each day's square is or be able to guess with math where it appears on the screen. Say each square is 30px and you know that the top corner is ALWAYS at 100,100, then you could tell it to use the mouse to click exactly. That is IF you can be sure the calendar always loads exactly and aren't doing any scrolling. It would be simpler to click on the date input box and type in the date if possible. Most calendar elements have an input you can use and it is faster too. Check out the [Puppeteer API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md) for more info on the mouse API if needed. Hey, good to have you here on stack! Welcome!